# Java Swing: alignment of right element in JSplitPane

Tags: java, swing, jsplitpane

For a programming exercise I am using a JSplitPane to make a window with a nice render of a fractal on the right, and some other garbage on the left. However, I have come across a very strange issue: the left element is completely fine, but the right element is also always left aligned. As far as I can tell, the right element is given the size of the right part of the screen, but it's always fully to the left, with the left element over top of it.

I create the JSplitPane and add its elements like this:

```
splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, true);

splitPane.add(sidebar, JSplitPane.LEFT);
splitPane.add(fractalWindow, JSplitPane.RIGHT);

frame.add(splitPane);
```

I've tried many different ways of constructing the JSplitPane and adding components to it (using setLeftComponent and setRightComponent, etc), but whatever I do, both components are always left aligned. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: sidebar is a JPanel, fractalWindow is a subclass of JPanel. I've tried adding fractalWindow to another JPanel and adding that to splitPane, but then the right component is not drawn at all. I have not specified a layout for JFrame frame.

EDIT 2: it's solved. My `Fractal` class was using methods `getX()` and `getY()` and I didn't know that I was overriding these. They would usually both just return 0, which meant that the JPanel was always put in the top left corner of the parent component.

Comment: This is probably caused by the LayoutManager of `fractalWindow`

Comment: have you tested my answer?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height.

Comment: I am trying to create an example that isn't 100s of lines, but I can't seem to recreate it. All I know is that in the fractal's `public void paintComponent(Graphics g)` method, the `Graphics` object is displayed in incorrect position. So there has to be something wrong in the layouts i've used or something. Can't figure out what, though.

Comment: If you have solved your own issue, it would benefit the community to self-answer your question with a formal answer, and accept it, so that users will be able to utilize it in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to put a JPanel in the right side, and place whatever you want of the JPanel:

```
splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, true);

splitPane.add(sidebar, JSplitPane.LEFT);
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.add(fractalWindow,BorderLayout.CENTER);
splitPane.add(panel, JSplitPane.RIGHT);

frame.add(splitPane);
```

That way, the panel aligns what you put in it to the center, and the split pane puts the panel on the right.

Comment: And i think that this is can be solution

Comment: I hope OP will think so, too

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the culprits were two methods in my Fractal class:

```
class Fractal extends JPanel {

    ...

    int xpos;
    int ypos;

    ...

    public int getX() {
        return xpos;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return ypos;
    }

    ...

}
```

These two methods override the `getX()` and `getY()` in `JPanel`, which are used to determine the JPanel's position in it's parent component. That is what caused the alignment to function incorrectly.